# What is operator for 'not' in React Router path?

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to display component only when the path is not '/my-profile'. What is equivalent for `!` sign in the react-router path?

I've tried something like this:

`` <Route path={`/(?!my-profile)`} component={Footer} /> ``

When I use code pasted above, I'm getting error:

`SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^\/((?:?\!my-profile))(?:\/(?=$))?(?=\/|$)/: Nothing to repeat`

Comment: This part `(?:?` starts a non capturing group and follows with a question mark to make something optional but there is nothing preceding the question mark to make optional. What are you trying to match? Is see 2 different patterns in the question.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I want to display Footer component on every route except `/my-profile` route. I'm sure that the error which I got is related with ```<Route path={`/(?!my-profile)`} component={Footer} />```. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with regex expression, so I don't know what does it mean.